# Spotify Web Api Error 500

Tags: runtime-error, spotify, playlist

Here is my code:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import json




token = util.prompt_for_user_token(
        username="xxxxxxxxxxx",
        scope="playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public",
        client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        client_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        redirect_uri="https://www.google.it/")

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

creaplaylist=spotify.user_playlist_create(user=spotify.me()["id"], name="some_playlist_name", public="true") 
print creaplaylist["id"]
#print json.dumps(creaplaylist, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

aggiungi_tracks_a_playlist=spotify.user_playlist_add_tracks(user=spotify.me()["id"], playlist_id=creaplaylist["id"], tracks = ["spotify:track:6RtPijgfPKROxEzTHNRiDp", "spotify:track:7IHOIqZUUInxjVkko181PB", "4VrWlk8IQxevMvERoX08iC", "http://open.spotify.com/track/3cySlItpiPiIAzU3NyHCJf"], position=1)
```

The response is this error:

```
    SpotifyException: https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/817fxfuzvi5d3vwhx6mefwrpf/playlists/13rW8OiBBdBwUYeJJSRvOI/tracks?position=1:
 Backend respond with 500
```

Where am I wrong? I can't add tracks to playlists.

Have you any advices?

Comment: I would try with just Spotify URIs and not track IDs, song links as the documentation only says URIs will work (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/add-tracks-to-playlist/). And if that doesn't work, try with position=0 maybe, if the playlist is empty to begin with then maybe position=1 is causing the issue (although I think it will be the first thing).

Comment: I haven't words. I'm feeling so stupid. It seems to be fixed now changing position from 1 to 0!